# How to add 100 images into 100 different pages of a google docs document?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have to add 100 images onto each page of my google docs document.

I tried adding images one by one, but obviously it's too time consuming.

One page for one image, that's it. I'll be really thankful if someone can help me! Thanks

Comment: Can I ask you about your current issue?

Comment: @Tanaike I have about a 100 images, okay. I want each image to be inserted in each page of a google doc. How can I write script for that, or is there any other way around?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your current issue from your replying. I apologize for my poor English skill.